# How to specify two level expand parameter in sap.ui.table?

Tags: sapui5

Using the below code I am able to populate values in the ANav only.What is the syntax for specifying inner Navigation property expand also.?

```
<Table id="table" selectionMode="MultiToggle" enableSelectAll="false"
            rows="{path: 'data>/ParentEntity', parameters : {expand : 'ANav/BNav'}}"
            enableBusyIndicator="true" visibleRowCount="15" threshold="100" width="auto" height="auto" noDataText="No Data">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have got a named model "data" you have to specify this model also in your expand parameter:

```
<Table id="table" selectionMode="MultiToggle" enableSelectAll="false"
        rows="{path: 'data>/ParentEntity', parameters : {expand : 'data>ANav/BNav'}}"
        enableBusyIndicator="true" visibleRowCount="15" threshold="100" width="auto" height="auto" noDataText="No Data">
```

Comment: I tried giving the model name also.But I can see the request failing in that case.

Comment: So please give more information. How does the request fail? Any logs in the console? how did you initialize your model?

Comment: Request fails with 500 internal server error. Because in the request url I can see  at the end $expand=data>ANav/BNav.  Also I initialized the model using "sap/ui/model/odata/ODataModel".